# How to prevent service on Oracle Service Bus (OSB) from changing xmlns prefix/aliases to random things?

Tags: xsd, wsdl, osb

We have a requirement to send specific namespace alias to the client and must use OSB.  The proxy service changes the name space aliases of exposed WSDL from what we carefully crafted.  I cannot find an option to prevent OSB from doing so.

For example

For namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/, The original wsdl start has

```
    <soap:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
```

But OSB exposes the WSDL like this

```
    <WL5G3N0:definitions xmlns:WL5G3N0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
```

The original alias "soap" is automatically changed to "WL5G3N0" by OSB and causing a problem.  Same type of renaming is also happening with many of the referenced XSD files.

How do we prevent the renaming of the aliases in OSB?

Comment: Prefixes have no meaning in XML, and they do not change the semantics of element names, as long as the namespace URI is the same. Why is this causing a problem? If it does, you should probably change your XML application.

Comment: This requirement is not to confirm WSDL / SOAP / WSDL / XSD standard.  This requirement is from client.  My question is "Can this feature be turned off?" and "How can it be turned off (if that is possible)"

Comment: I agree with @MathiasMüller.  What it sounds like your client is doing is not parsing XML, but doing a string comparison on something, and when the schema's prefixes are changed (as would be allowed per XML standards), they can't handle it.

Comment: I am not trying to say OSB is behaving wrong.  I am just trying to figure out if it can be turned off.  Can it be turned off?  Or OSB does not allow us to turn it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support.oracle.com responded to my SR 3-10633538571 and they officially confirmed that automatic renaming of prefix cannot be disabled in OSB 11g.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from the Oracle community forum <strike>and I am closing this</strike>.  Someone who seems to be knowledgeable about OSB said there is no known way for him to turn the auto renaming off.

It seems the answer is "No, you cannot turn off the automatic renaming of xmlns prefix in OSB"

Comment: Forgot the link to the thread https://community.oracle.com/message/13023796#13023796

Comment: BTW, this is not a forum, and questions aren't "closed" like that.

Answer (score 0):

Service Bus takes your WSDL (called resource WSDL) and creates from it an effective WSDL, by replacing the port, service and other sections of the original WSDL.

Renaming of the namespace prefixes is part of this transformation. You cannot avoid creation of the effective WSDL. The transformation does not preserve your prefixes, which means you have to live with that.